# How to toggle an on/off switch with redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I`m trying to implement a switch that can be switched on and off and according to the state a different image and text is shown. With the help of a tutorial I did the following:

First I created store.js:

```
    import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import switchReducer from './switch';

    export const store = configureStore({
       reducer: {
          switchVal: switchReducer
       }
    });
```

Then I created switch.js

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const switchSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'alarm',
        initialState: {
          active: true
        },
        reducers: {
          toggleSwitch: (state) => {
            state.active = !state.active;
          },
        }
    });

    export const toggleSwitch = switchSlice.actions.toggleSwitch;
    export default switchSlice.reducer;
```

In App.js I imported {store} and wrapped  around my BottomTab Navigator.

Now the switch is in Alarm.js which looks like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, Pressable, Switch } from 'react-native';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

    import { globalStyles } from '../components/globalStyles';
    import { toggleSwitch } from '../components/switch';


    function Alarm({navigation}) {
      const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.switchValue);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const alarmEnabled = require('../images/Alarm_enabled.png');
      const alarmDisabled = require('../images/Alarm_disabled.png');

      function toggleSwitchHandler() {
        if (switchValue == true) {
          dispatch(toggleSwitch(value));
        } else {
          dispatch(toggleSwitch(value));
        }
      }


       return ( 
         <ScrollView>
           <View style={globalStyles.containerBodyAlarm}>

             <View style={globalStyles.containerMainAlarm}>
               <View style={globalStyles.containerImageAlarm}>
                 <Image style={{ width: 130, height: 130, resizeMode: 'contain', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 10}} source={switchValue ? alarmDisabled : alarmEnabled } />
               </View>
               <View style={globalStyles.containerButtonAlarm}>
                 <Text style={globalStyles.textButtonAlarm}>{switchValue ? 'Alarm is deactivated' : 'Alarm is activated'}</Text>
                 <Switch
                   trackColor={{false: '#919190', true: '#000099'}}
                   thumbColor={'#5E5E5D'}
                   value={switchValue}
                   onValueChange= {toggleSwitchHandler}
                 />
                 <Text style={globalStyles.textButtonAlarm2}>{switchValue ? 'activate' : 'deactivate'}</Text>
               </View>
             </View>
          </View>
         </ScrollView>
       );
      }

     export default Alarm;


     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       pressed: {
       opacity: 0.7,
     },
```

Unfortunately it's not working. What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry for the bad coding, I'm not good at it.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial state looks like:

```js
initialState: {
    active: true
},
```

However, you are getting the value by doing:

```js
const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.switchValue);
```

That does not exist, it needs to be:

```
const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.active);
```

---

```js
function toggleSwitchHandler() {
    if (switchValue == true) {
        dispatch(toggleSwitch(value));
    } else {
        dispatch(toggleSwitch(value));
    }
}
```

The `if` here has no use since both callers have the same props.

Also, `value` does not exist, since you're flipping the boolean inside the reducer, no need for the param.

Change it to:

```js
function toggleSwitchHandler() {
    dispatch(toggleSwitch());
}
```

To invert the current boolean

Comment: Thank you so much! I corrected everything and now the app is running but the switch doesn't work. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

you can make 2 reducers, one with value true the other with value false

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialStateValue = {
   active: true
}

const switchSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'alarm',
    initialState: initialStateValue,
    reducers: {
      toggleOn: (state = initialStateValue) => {
        state.active = true;
      },
      toggleOff: (state = initialStateValue) => {
        state.active = false;
      }
    }
});

export const {toggleOn, toggleOff} = switchSlice.actions;
export default switchSlice.reducer;
```

get the value of toggle

```
const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.alarm.active);
```

use it

```
function toggleSwitchHandler() {
   if (switchValue == true) {
      dispatch(toggleOff());
   } else {
      dispatch(toggleOn());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemented everything you suggested but the App didn't run, so I changed const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.alarm.active); to const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.active);. Now the App is running but the switch is still not working. Do you have any idea why? Any ideas are greatly appreciated, I just can't seem to get this App working.

Comment: in function toggleSwitchHandler add a console.log(switchValue) above if() see if you get true or false value

Comment: I get an undefined

Comment: whats the error you get when you use useSelector as i said?

Comment: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.alarm.active')"

Comment: i edited, added initialStateValue

Comment: Thank you. I get the same error message with state.alarm.active. and the App runs with state.active but the switch is still not switchable.

Comment: rename "switchVal" to "alarm" in reducer in store.js

Comment: With 'alarm' instead of 'switchVal' and state.alarm.active it works!! Thank you so much for your help, I've been trying to solve this for a weeks!

Answer (score 0):

```
setLogin: (state, action) => {
  const toggle = (input) => !input;
  state.active = toggle(state.active);
},
```

I was having the same issue and came up with above solution. :)

Comment: Why not just `state.active = !state.active;`?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello.**

I came across your question by accident.

And I think it's simpler than that.

Is it real? Maybe so:

**switch.js**

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
   active: true
}

const switchSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'alarm',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      toggleSwitch(state) {
        state.active = !state.active;
      }
    }
});

export const { toggleSwitch } = switchSlice.actions;
export default switchSlice.reducer;
```

And then in the component call:

**Alarm.js**

```js
...
import { toggleSwitch } from '../store/reducers/switch' // switch.js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
...

export function Alarm({navigation}) {

      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const { active } = useSelector(state => state.yourReducer);

      const alarmEnabled = require('../images/Alarm_enabled.png');
      const alarmDisabled = require('../images/Alarm_disabled.png');


       return ( 
         <ScrollView>
           <View style={globalStyles.containerBodyAlarm}>

             <View style={globalStyles.containerMainAlarm}>
               <View style={globalStyles.containerImageAlarm}>
                 <Image style={{ width: 130, height: 130, resizeMode: 'contain', marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 10}} source={active ? alarmDisabled : alarmEnabled } />
               </View>
               <View style={globalStyles.containerButtonAlarm}>
                 <Text style={globalStyles.textButtonAlarm}>{active ? 'Alarm is deactivated' : 'Alarm is activated'}</Text>
                 <Switch
                   trackColor={{false: '#919190', true: '#000099'}}
                   thumbColor={'#5E5E5D'}
                   value={active}
                   onValueChange= {() => dispatch(toggleSwitch())}
                 />
                 <Text style={globalStyles.textButtonAlarm2}>{active ? 'activate' : 'deactivate'}</Text>
               </View>
             </View>
          </View>
         </ScrollView>
       );
      }


     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       pressed: {
       opacity: 0.7,
     },
```

So you don't mutate in your redus, you mutate in your component by calling the dispatcher. Every time the state changes, this will call the function from "switch" and change it to the opposite value